# When do we use prescriptive vs descriptive models?

Tags: user-research

In Design Methodology we can use

- **descriptive models** such as `hierarchical task analysis`,
- **prescriptive models** such as `user stories`

...To capture and understand the **context of use** as well as the **user mental model**.

The question is: how do we use them appropriately? Meaning *when* and *why* do we use either descriptive/prescriptive models?

Comment: I think for the purpose of the UXSE format, you'll probably need to provide a more specific example because the type of models you use would probably depend on a lot of different factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to think of them as **learning** vs **sharing** tools and techniques.

Descriptive artifacts give you and your team a way to analyze what is needed or what the current user process is. I'm a firm believer in the [Jobs to Be Done](http://a.co/d/cWCsXJS) framework so these artifacts let you identify the real reason for a hire.

I like prescriptive artifacts as a way to share findings with the rest of the team. User Stories, Journey Maps, etc give you a way to share the analysis of raw information in a package that other makers can get behind. I don't think it's an accident that Agile Methodology employs User Stories to help developers know what to build and allow QA to understand what success looks like.